# anchor href get current url and append on next page with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to get current page url and append it to the next page url on anchor click.

html:

```
<a class="JS-hrefURI" href="">Make reservation</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $(".JS-hrefURI").attr('href', "reservation.php?res=" + document.URL);
 });
```

When I inspect this anchor on first page load, my href is empty, and after refresh it finally gets current page url appended.
This is kinda working but my page just refreshes on first click and nothing else happens. On second click on anchor it works well and url is appended.

Optionally, instead of whole "document.URL" link, is there a way to pass only specific part of url what comes after "art=" in this example link (/article.php?art=item_id_number) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.location`.

```
// for your example '/article.php?art=item_id_number'
window.location.search.split('=')[1]; // -> item_id_number
```

And you should use `encodeURIComponent()` when constructing the URL.